# How to get dependent drop-down lists to work in exported workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still reasonably new to VBA and feel I'm punching a little above my weight, so hopefully someone can help.

I need to issue a spreadsheet to people in my company which they can fill out and send it back. This needs to be done multiple times, so I have tried to automate this as much as possible. The source data is pasted in an "input" tab - this is then pivoted by user and input into a template tab. I can select any user and run a macro which does this and exports the filled out template to a new workbook.

In this template tab, I have dependent drop-down lists, which I have done by data validation - this relies on named ranges from the "coding" tab, which is also exported. One named range shows a list of values, and the other indexes over this and matches it to the required cell, to ensure only valid combinations are shown.

My issue is that the new workbook must not contain any links to the master - it should function completely in its own right. However, something is going wrong with the data validation/named ranges. Either some named ranges are being deleted (I know which bit of code is doing that but without it you get prompted to update links) or the data validation formula links back to the original workbook and doesn't work. I cannot find another way of achieving what I need without this particular data validation set up, so I need to try and adjust my macro to cater for this.

Is it possible to simply copy the template and coding tabs, with all the data validation, to a new workbook and break all links to the original, so that there are no startup prompts and the drop-downs all work?

```
Sub Copy_To_New_Workbook()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim name As String
Dim ExternalLinks As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim strFolder As String, strTempfile As String

name = Worksheets("Control").Cells(14, 7).Value

Let FileNameIs = Range("Filepath").Value & Range("FileName").Value

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Coding").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.name = "Coding"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transactions").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Coding")
ActiveSheet.name = "Transactions"
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ExternalLinks = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

ExternalLinks = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinks)
    wb.BreakLink name:=ExternalLinks(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
Next x

Dim objDefinedName As Object

   For Each objDefinedName In wb.Names
        If InStr(objDefinedName.RefersTo, "[") > 0 Then
            objDefinedName.Delete
        End If
    Next objDefinedName

On Error GoTo 0

wb.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameIs, FileFormat:=52

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Update: I have solved this problem by restructuring my data validation using the INDIRECT formula. This isn't ideal for my situation and has caused other issues, but it means I can solve the issues with the named ranges being exported and breaking the links.